# SharePoint Graph API to join an existing Team Site

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to join a SharePoint team site using Graph API. I can only see Create Team, Add Member, etc. But not seeing this anywhere in the documentation. Is there an API to join an existing public team site via API?

Comment: What do you mean by "join an existing public team site"?  Is it adding member into a Sharepoint?

Comment: Yes, I mean adding myself to the team. I think I found something, I believe Adding to Group implies adding to the Team.. Hope I am right?

Comment: Thanks.. yes your answer helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [Adding or managing members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-create-group-and-team#adding-or-managing-members).

> To add members after a team is created, you use the [add member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
> operation.

So you are right. Adding a member into a group will also adding it to the associated teams.

You can use [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to have a quick test.